# How to Auto-Generate Filenames for InfoPath Forms in SharePoint 2013 Form Library?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

I have created a Form Library in SharePoint 2013. When I create new Item in this library it
asks me for a name.

I need a way to generate that name dynamically.

I searched the net and found a blog: http://claytoncobb.com/2009/06/20/auto-generating-filenames-for-infopath-forms/

But in this blog it is described for SharePoint 2007 or 2010 and InfoPath 2007 and InfoPath 2010, not for SharePoint 2013 and InfoPath 2013. How can I generate file name dynamically in the form library in SharePoint 2013?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the file name by using the expression concat("SomeText","-",today()).

On the data connection Wizard choose the Create new connection to Submit data, then select to a document library (or list) on a sharepoint site and finally add the expression:

concat("SomeText","-",today())

[image]

Comment: I created a blank form in InfoPath 2013 I created the connection as you specified I published it in my Form Library when I click on add new document at first when I submitted it created my form with: FRMS-2014-12-31 dynamically when I clicked again it did not create new one

Comment: if different user submit same day